# Remove HTML tag from string with para as a space

Tags: c#, regex

How to remove all html tags from string but para `<p>` tag should be replaced with space.

```
HTMLCode =  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(HTMLCode,"<p>", "<p> ");

HTMLCode = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(HTMLCode, "<[^>]*>", "");
```

I want to merge above 2 expression in one such that it will remove all html tags with `<p>` replaced with space.
eg. If string is `"This is<p>ADP</p>"`, expected o/p should be `"This is ADP"` not `"This isADP"`

Comment: Why not to use `HtmlAgilityPack` instead of `Regex`? Its more flexible than `Regex`

Answer (score 0):

Remove All tags except `<p>` and add space after it.

```
public static string StripHtml(string text)
    {
        string ignorePattern = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            text = text.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            text = text.Replace("&gt;", ">");

            text = text.Replace("<p>", "<p> ");
           // ignorePattern = string.Format("{0}(?!p)(?!/p)", ignorePattern);

            ignorePattern = string.Format(@"<{0}[^<]*>", ignorePattern);

            text = Regex.Replace(text, ignorePattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to achieve this in only one replace call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var HTMLCode = "This is<div><p>ADP</p></div>";
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
                        .Replace(HTMLCode, @"<[^>]*>", " ").Trim();
```

Comment: Here it uses 3 replace call. Is it possible with one replace call?